# Having trouble sending payment requests to Chase Paymentech

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a CLR to connect to Chase Paymentech payment portal. I worked on this a few years ago and it was working fine. Chase has updated their servers and now i'm running into a lot of issues. We use a third party proxy for PCI compliancy and we have checked the following:

- Security requirements (we are SHA2 and TLS1.2 enabled so that should be fine)
- Connection requirements (server IPs have been authenticated and confirmed whitelist)
- company orbital username and password verified

When I run my console application (C# ASP.NET), when i send the request, i get the following error:

> Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1',
>   but expected 'text/xml'.
>
> The request failed with the error message:
>
> --
>
> ```
> <title>paymentech.net</title>
>
> <meta http-equiv="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://www.chasepaymentech.com/">
> ```

Now my third party partner says that I am getting a 100-continue response so I added the following code to get around it:

> System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

I am still getting the above response content type error. Any help or requests for more information would be appreciated.

Comment: The response code sent with that HTML document is 100 Continue, even when you've set `Expect100Continue` to false? Can you get your third party to capture the request headers you're actually sending to double check whether there's an Expect header present?

Comment: Sounds like your application is expecting xml back from Chase, but they are sending text/html.